# Telegram bot with Aiogram can't send local photos

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I'm coding a telegram bot with python and Aiogram.
I can't send local photos on the chat but if I link one that's from google it's OK.  Why is that?

```
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    percorso_img = script_directory + '\\images\\volume1.jpg'
    print(percorso_img)

    await message.answer_photo('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71Rpwr00gpS._AC_UF1000,1000_QL80_.jpg')
    await message.answer_photo(percorso_img)
```

This is my code, the first photo is sent on the bot as it is a link from the internet.
The second which is a path to a local photo is not. The path is correct as printed on the terminal and by clicking it to open the photo.

This is the error that I get
`TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Wrong port number specified in the URL`

I've tried other methods like

```
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
percorso_immagine = os.path.join(script_directory, 'images', 'volume1.jpg')

with open(percorso_immagine, 'rb') as immagine_file:
    input_file = types.InputFile(immagine_file)

await message.answer_photo(input_file)
```

and i get other errors

`Errore nell'invio dell'immagine: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile with abstract method read`

also tried

```
   photo=open(percorso_img, "rb")
   await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
```

but

```
ValidationError: 2 validation errors for SendPhoto
photo.is-instance[InputFile]
  Input should be an instance of InputFile [type=is_instance_of, input_value=<_io.BufferedReader name=...m\\images\\volume1.jpg'>, input_type=BufferedReader]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/is_instance_of
photo.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=<_io.BufferedReader name=...m\\images\\volume1.jpg'>, input_type=BufferedReader]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/string_type`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this way for local photo:

```py
await message.answer_photo(
        types.FSInputFile(path=path_to_photo), caption="Some kind of caption"
    )
```

And this for photo from the internet:

```py
await call.message.answer_photo(
        photo=URLInputFile(
            url=photo_url,
            filename=f"picture.png"
        ), caption="Some kind of caption"
    )
```

I tested the performance of these methods on aiogram version 3 and Python 3.11 works

Comment: await message.answer_photo(
            types.InputFile("D:\workspaces\vscode-workspace\Bot_Telegram\py\V2\aiogram\images\volume2.jpg"), caption="Some kind of caption"
        )
    await message.answer_photo(
            types.InputFile("D:\\workspaces\\vscode-workspace\\Bot_Telegram\\py\\V2\\aiogram\\images\\volume2.jpg"), caption="Some kind of caption"
        )
    await message.answer_photo(
            types.InputFile("D:/workspaces/vscode-workspace/Bot_Telegram/py/V2/aiogram/images/volume2.jpg"), caption="Some kind of caption"
        )

i've tried all this with no resul

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to replace `types.InputFile` on `types.FSInputFile` and include raw string in path to photo